# How to do a screen saver in flutter desktop app?

Tags: flutter

With **Flutter**, I'm looking for a way to put a **screen saver on a desktop app** after X min of inactivity. How can I do this? Considering that on desktop, the `AppLifecycleState` doesn't work (there are issues on the github flutter repo), I've also tried cheating with a `NavigatorObserver` or even tracking the mouse with `MouseRegion`.